# out of the blue I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: cache is not defined" on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, reference

I have this function which autocompletes a form:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#models").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function(request, response) {
                var term = request.term;
                $.getJSON(URL, request, function(data, status, xhr) {
                    cache[term] = data;
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log(data);
                    response(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Everything was working normally until I had to rollback migrations and migrate and seed again and now I am getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: cache is not defined

I `console.log(term);` I do get what I am typing in the form so I don't understand why `cache` is not defined when `term` is.

Comment: Well, where is `cache` defined...?

Comment: isn't cache a function that is caching term?

Comment: If you're asking if it's a built in function, then no it's not standard Javascript  functionality. If you're using a library which provides a `cache` array, then you may need to missing the reference to that library on this page. To be honest the use of any caching is a little redundant anyway, as jQuery will do that for you for AJAX requests.

Comment: well, why wasn't it showing as an error before? The script was working perfectly as it is written in this page.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer that. All I can tell you is something must have changed somewhere to affect this code. If you're using any kind of source code control I would suggest you do a diff on the current version of the code and the previous one you rolled back from.